# PeerJS Server connecting SSL

Tags: server, peerjs, peer

I started my own PeerJS server, everything works, but now I don't know how to connect an ssl certificate to it. The documentation says:

Simply pass in PEM-encoded certificate and key.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { PeerServer } = require('peer');

const peerServer = PeerServer({
  port: 9000,
  ssl: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/your/ssl/key/here.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/your/ssl/certificate/here.crt')
  }
});
```

and where to insert this code, where this file is located?
please explain who knows...

Answer (score 0):

This code should be added to the server.js file

Comment: Take a look again at [answer] to see how you can make this a complete answer